# What is the most efficent / fastest way to iterate values in an iptables rule?

Tags: iptables, variable

I'm trying to write an iptables rule that applies to multiple interfaces based on a variable. Which of the rules is more efficient / faster ? Is there a better way to write this rule with a minimum of code ?

```
#Variable
Ext_INTF="eth0 usb0 tun0 tun1"
```

1)

```
for i in $Ext_INTF;
do
iptables -A FORWARD -i $i -j DROP
done
```

2)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i $Ext_INTF -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 doesn't work — it produces an invalid `iptables` invocation. Whatever you thought it might do, it only adds one iptables rule, and you can't match an arbitrary set of interfaces in a single rule. Method 1 is the normal way and pretty much the only way.

Not that efficiency of setting iptables rules is a concern. You'd have to work very hard to do something noticeably non-optimal. The concerns here are to get the rules right, possibly the efficiency of the rules themselves, and keep the script readable so that it's easy to maintain.

Writing `$Ext_INTF` — a variable substitution outside double quotes — splits the value of the variable into whitespace-separated parts, and then expands each part as a wildcard pattern matching file names. Here the variable doesn't contain any wildcard character (`\[*?`). Thus `for i in $Ext_INTF; …` loops over the words in the value of the variable. [In general you should only use variable substitutions inside double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), because `$Ext_INTF` means “the value of `Ext_INTF`” only inside double quotes, but here you want the splitting to happen, and the parts don't contain any shell wildcard characters.

```
Ext_INTF="eth0 usb0 tun0 tun1"
for i in $Ext_INTF; do
  iptables -A FORWARD -i "$i" -j DROP
done
```

In bash and ksh, but not in plain sh, you can use an array instead of a string variable. (And in zsh you must use an array or explicitly request splitting with `$=Ext_INTF`.) You have to type a few more characters, but this makes the intent clearer, and allows the elements to contain whitespace and wildcards if need be.

```
Ext_INTF=(eth0 usb0 tun0 tun1)
for i in "${Ext_INTF[@]}"; do
  iptables -A FORWARD -i "$i" -j DROP
done
```

Comment: What are the consequences of not placing the $i in quotes ("$i") ?

Comment: @uihdff [See the thread I linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). See also [Stéphane Chazelas's examples of how it can be a security hole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells/171347#171347).

Comment: For brevity, I wrote iptables instead of $IPTABLES which points to /sbin/iptables. Does that pose a vulnerability ? All referenced variables whether they are multi-valued or not, should be double quoted, correct ?

Comment: @uihdff If you know that the value of `IPTABLES` doesn't contain any whitespace or wildcard characters and you aren't changing the value of `IFS` then writing `$IPTABLES` without quotes is ok. However making such assumptions defeats the purpose of using a variable. What if you want to use a different version of `iptables` that's located in `/opt/advanced networking/bin`? Either write `iptables` (there's very little reason to replace `iptables` by something else) or `"$IPTABLES"`.